# jQuery: how to position/animate an absolutely positioned element relative to another element

Tags: jquery, menu, css-position

So, I am trying to create a vertical navigation menu that includes a stack (rows) of navigation items. When one of these rows is selected, I want a menu to slide out from above (and beneath) and when the top of this sub menu reaches the bottom of the row that was clicked. These sub menus should also have a starting position where the sub menu bottom is equal to the related navigation item bottom, so that upon animate downward, it is immediately visible.

This positioning, the stop and start points, can be seen in this fiddle ->  http://jsfiddle.net/pGfCX/57/. Just take note of the start and end points. The rest of the fiddle is broken due to the nature of position:relative.

I thought that z-index could fix the pushing of the subsequent navigation items (as you can see in the fiddle just linked)... however that doesn't seem to work. It looks like only position:absolute will enable the proper overlapping (i.e. sub menu hides beneath the elements above it and covers those below it). Unfortunately, this has it's faults as well. As you can see in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pGfCX/60/. You will notice that the starting position and ending position is always the same because I'm using the same class every time. Although I could specifically position every single sub menu as it's own unique ID, that would be very inefficient and difficult to maintain.

Bsically, I need a mix of the two approaches... relative positioning for the start/end positions and absolute to enable the proper overlapping.

Hopefully this makes sense... I really need help. I'm stuck with the two approaches and neither working. It's frustrating.

Here is my current jQuery code:

```
$('.row').click(function() {

    // make all siblings AFTER row clicked get this class to reduce z-index and allow the menu to display above these rows (while still remaining below the rows above)

    $(this).nextAll().addClass('rowZ');
    $(this).next('.menu').show()
    $(this).next('.menu').animate({'top':'0'});

});

// when menu is out, the row clicked is the header row, upon clicking this, the related menu (and by default, all subsequent menus within) animate back up and hide

$('.rowHead').click(function() {

    $(this).next('.menu').animate({'top':'-100%'});
    $(this).next('.menu').hide();

});
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT*** New approach... menu within the navigational item, to allow it to have absolute positioning and be relative to the navigational item. However, the z-index seems off (i.e. it's animating over top the navigational item (it's parent) though the z-index would suggest otherwise:

http://jsfiddle.net/pGfCX/81/

Comment: Having difficulty trying to figure out what you're actually trying to accomplish here - can you upate the description a bit? I think a verbal explanation would be better since both of those fiddles are semi-broken

Comment: I'll try and be more clear... you've gotta mash the fiddles together to create what I want, lol. Hold on, I'll explain.

Comment: _"Additionally, I'd like the starting point for these sub menus to also be relative to the navigation item click"_ - Have you tried putting the sub-menus inside their parent menu items in your markup? An absolutely positioned element's coordinates are still relative to its parent if the parent has `position:relative`.

Comment: So, if I put the sub menu within the parent and position it absolute, I can get it positioned correctly? I haven't tried that. But does this fix the issue of the overlapping? i.e. can I have the child within the parent but beneath it and it's previous parents' siblings (uncles/aunts? lol) and overlapping the subsequent parents' siblings? I'll try that... let me see.

Comment: I think I understand what you're trying to do. See if my fiddle works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: rolled back to this revision, because, although this wasn't an answer, it would better serve as a similar alternative.

http://jsfiddle.net/pGfCX/70/

This seems to be working as you like. Keep relative positioning, fix up your z-indexes, and give .row a background color :) confused me endlessly because my z-index looked broken, but it was because the elements were going UNDER .row (you could see the text on top), but because it had a grey background on container, it appeared as though it wasn't behind row. Should be a pure CSS fix:

```
#container{
    background:grey;
    width:100px;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:1;
}
.row{
    width:100px;
    height:40px;
    cursor:pointer;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1100;
    background-color: pink;
}
 .row:hover{
    background:red;
}
.menu{
    background:yellow;
    width:100px;
    height:300px;
    position:relative;
    top:-100%;
    left:0;
    z-index:2;
    display:none;
}
.menu .row {
    z-index: 10;   
}
```

​

Comment: I don't want the other elements pushed out of the way... I want the menu to overlap the subsequent rows. However, I will say this, I'm warming up to the idea of it simply expanding and leaving the other navigational items to be pushed further down. I guess it doesn't hurt to have them... and the solution is there. But I am still curious if my original design implementation is possible? Btw, I appreciate the help. Let me know if this comment clears up the design intention.

Comment: Yes. That is VERY close. If I change the position of menu to bottom:100% (not sure why top:-100% isn't the same? but I digress) it then starts properly and is ending properly. However, it is animating over top the upper items (it should be beneath those and only be visible above the subsequent rows). But the .row z-index is higher (1100) than the menu (1000) so I don't see why that's happening?

Comment: Also, in regards to that first fiddle you posted (since like I said, I am warming up to that design approach)... the one thing I'm wondering about is why that grey background shows up before the menu animation. Instead of those rows moving down simultaneously with the animation. I suppose it has something to do with the .show() function.

Comment: I see what u are saying - I found something weird. http://jsfiddle.net/pGfCX/117/ looks like I was able to use a negative  zindex and now it goes behind the text, but it doesn't go behind the background... The truth is, the problem is in your markup. What you're trying to achieve requires that the first level .row and the .menu including it's .rows are on the same level. Ur z-index issues are occuring because .menu and .menu .row are children of an element you wish to have absolute and higher z-index

Comment: Yes, but if I have them on the same level (I do in one of the fiddles), the overlapping works properly, but I can't get them to start/stop in the same position... unless they are children with absolute or siblings and relative. But both those scenarios lead to the z-index issues. Bleh. As of now, I'm gonna call this a loss and go with your fiddle. To be honest, that's more useable anyhow... it's not like I have limited vertical screen space, so expanding but still seeing the initial navigation items is a plus. Thank you for helping. I REALLY REALLY appreciate it.

Comment: Also... and could you perhaps answer the question regarding the fiddle #70. I wonder if it's possible to have the items animate with the menu simultaneously rather than moving immediately and then the space being filled in by the menu (without going through the hoops of animate those subsequent rows themselves). It might just be a byproduct of .show() or something though.

Comment: Haha sorry, I think I'm maxxed out of ideas. Just running into the same troubles you are :) I'll try to take a look at 70 again in a bit. Are you talking about the fact that the full height of menu pops in before the animation?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20369/discussion-between-jstacks-and-keith)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't set a `top` rule for those absolutely-positioned `.menu` elements, they'll hang out directly below the relatively-positioned `.row` elements preceding each one instead of floating to the top of `#container`. Then, you can use jQuery's `slideDown()` and `slideUp()` animations to show/hide the menus from their desired position.

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/pGfCX/142/)** at jsFiddle

**Example code**

CSS

```
#container {
    background:#666;
    width:100px;
    height:100%;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
   z-index: 10;
}
.row {
    width:100px;
    height:40px;
    cursor:pointer;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    line-height: 40px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 40px 40px -40px #fff;
}
.row:hover {
    background:red;
}
.row.active {
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
}    
.menu {
    background: #999;
    width:100px;
    height:auto;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    z-index: 2;
    display:none;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

JS

```
$('.menu').prev('.row').click(function() {

    // Stops the handler from firing if an animation is in progress
    if (!$('#container').is('.working')) {

        // Begin manipulating the menu...
        $('#container').addClass('working');

        // Defines how fast menus will slide up/down
        var slideSpeed = 200;    

        // If menus need to be hidden, wait for them to slide up, otherwise, don't bother
        var d = ($(this).parent().children('.row.active').length > 0) ? slideSpeed : 0;

        // IF this rowhead is collapsed, expand it and collapse expanded siblings
        if (!$(this).is('.active')) {

// Collapse the active menu at this level, if any             
            $(this).siblings('.row.active').removeClass('active').next('.menu').slideUp(d, function(){
             // When this menu is hidden, collapse all expanded submenus
             $(this).find('.row').removeClass('active');
             $(this).find('.menu').hide();
        });

        // Expand this menu after others have finished collapsing
        window.setTimeout(function(a){

            // Fallback for bodyless rowheads: skips wait if this rowhead has no menu
            b = ($(a).parent().find('.row.active').length > 0) ? slideSpeed : 0;

            // Expand this menu
            $(a).addClass('active').next('.menu').slideDown(slideSpeed, function(){
                // Ready container for more interaction after menu (if any) expands 
                $('#container').removeClass('working');            
            });
        },d,this);
    }

    // Otherwise, if this menu is expanded, collapse it                          
    else $(this).removeClass('active').next('.menu').slideUp(d, function(){ 

         // When this menu is hidden, collapse all expanded submenus
         $(this).find('.row').removeClass('active');
         $(this).find('.menu').hide();

         //Ready the container for more interaction        
         $('#container').removeClass('working');
        });
    }
});
```

​